# Is there a GUI tool for managing VirtualBox drives/machines?

Tags: virtualization, virtualbox

Is there a Windows GUI tool (or even a collection of "Send to..." scripts) to manage VirtualBox .vdi drives and/or virtual machines?

What I'm looking for is a way to right-click on a drive and clone it without resorting to the command line.  A tool that covers other tasks is a plus.

I have a set of self written Nautilus scripts for Ubuntu... However, I dual boot and would like similar functionality in Windows without rewriting them in .bat (teh sux) format.

[EDIT] For those interested here's the nautilus script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Chris Nava
# VBoxManage clonevdi

IFS=$'\t\n'

DIRNAME=`dirname $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`
BASENAME=`basename $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS .vdi`

cd "$DIRNAME"

NEWFILE=`zenity --entry --text="Clone Virtual Drive" --entry-text="$BASENAME"_clone`

if VBoxManage clonevdi "$BASENAME.vdi" "$NEWFILE.vdi"
then
zenity --info --title "Clone Virtual Drive" --text "Cloned $BASENAME.vdi to $NEWFILE.vdi"
exit 0
else
rm "$DIRNAME/$NEWFILE.vdi"
zenity --error --title "Clone Virtual Drive" --text "Cannot clone $DIRNAME/$BASENAME.vdi"
exit 1
fi
```

And the Windows batch script: (much less robust)

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Sun\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd "%1" "%~d1%~p1%~n1_cloned_%date:~-4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%~x1"
pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any GUI tools that you can use to manage this. You could always install perl or Python, or if you're really hooked on shell, [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)/[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). I would recommend you give batch files a try though, it would be the cleanest solution, despite its shortcomings.

Comment: No thanks.  My primary access to these files is via Windows Explorer so I would like a solution that integrates with that.  Adding another shell just makes me need to type more. ;-)  Looks like I'm going to need to do some batch scripting for use with "Send To..."

Answer (score 1):

Check these following 3 links:

- http://clandestine.dk/page/VBoxManage-CloneHD-GUI.aspx
- http://www.die-rooter.de/ITworks/archives/4-VirtualBox-CloneVDI.html#extended
- http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=22422

Comment: The middle link is broken.  Link-only answers are considered "Not An Answer" because when the link moves/dies, the advice is lost.  This whole answer should be converted into a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using vbox for a while and there is no GUI that I know of..

I did find a few links on VBoxMagage that might be of assistance to you though (they were with me).

[UbuntuGeek: How to control virtual machines with VBoxManage](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-control-virtual-machines-virtualbox-using-vboxmanage.html)

[Secrets for controlling VirtualBox from the command line](http://linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8224-secrets-for-controlling-virtualbox-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

There is a VirtualBox Manager GUI, both for Linux and for Windows version. I use it all the time on my Debian (just running 'virtualbox' opens up the GUI interface). You can see it on screenshots available on main VirtualBox site: http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Screenshots

In that interface you can find a .vdi manager which will let you mount/umount,  create new disk images, etc. Besides, those disk images are just plain files in `~/.VirtualBox/` directory, which you can simply copy using your standard system tools.

Comment: There's no option to "clone" a .vdi in the virtualbox provided GUI.  (Which is ironic because it's the most frequent thing I do to those files.)  Copying the files results in conflicts when you try to import them.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple script to clone a VirtualBox machine. It is not GUI but I think it can help you - it can create a clone from any snapshot. See my [blog post](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-clone-virtualbox-virtual-machine.html) where you can download the script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gui for VirtualBox. I'm using it whthout any problems. It's called PhpVirtualbox and it can be downloaded here: http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/

Comment: He wants to manage the disks, not the VMs themselves.